# Is narrowing down a union type with optional chaining possible?

Tags: typescript

I have a [discriminating union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions), simplified into this example.

```
type FoobarEvent = FooEvent | BarEvent;

interface FooEvent {
    type: 'foo';
    foo: {
        name: string;
    }
}

interface BarEvent {
    type: 'bar';
    bar: {
        id: string;
    }
}
```

Of course I can check the discriminant and get the union type narrowed down properly.

```
// let's assume this exists
declare const foobarEvent: FoobarEvent;

let fooName: string | undefined;

if (foobarEvent.type === 'foo') {
    fooName = foobarEvent.foo.name;
}
```

However I want to avoid this if-block, so I tried to use optional chaining to narrow down the type, but that doesn't work because one of the unions doesn't have the field I'm trying to access.

```
const fooNameByChaining = foobarEvent.foo?.name;
```

> Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'FoobarEvent'.
>  Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'BarEvent'.

So apparently the narrowing would need to happen before the optional chaining. Is this a limitation of TypeScript's type system or could this be added to Typescript as a feature? Or is there another way around this that I'm not aware of?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nARgQwE4FEBuEB2woC8sCWu+APlAEJql4DcAUIwJZ4SoBmyAxtPHDr4A3oyjiooSAC4oAck4I5TCVEVxZo1apzIAthFkBnYKjYBzFRIC+jW63Zde0Ghmx4oWiVMPyUqZTEJf00g7SgWABNjUwsrcVt7SIgeABs0aB44HBM1BH8hWQEC92AmRlSIfHUAOX1fEzMccyhKAFccZM42CEjylk4oAAp1ErIAOh9CAiIFJQBKTzC8uDqDQhWxvHH1cd0DJnssnOqENYgqEABhAAtkNgsN0dpSnYQAfj36piA)

Comment: "*When I try to use optional chaining to narrow down the type*" optional chaining doesn't narrow the type. See [Narrowing in the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) for which constructs actually do narrowing. [You can use the `in` operator](https://tsplay.dev/WoqrjN) for example.

Comment: I'm confused because your initial declaration of const `foobarEvent` does not have a `type` field. It's only that type because your forced it with `as`.

Comment: @spender don't think it matters. It's just code to showcase the behaviour, after all. EDIT: although the `as` is apparently used because the object isn't even a valid `FooEvent` as it doesn't have a `type`

Comment: Yup sorry just forgot to add the `type` field in the event, edited it now. The point of the question is to find out whether it would be possible to do type narrowing by optional chaining. Adjusted the title as well.

Comment: Its just common misunderstanding that we can write TS the same we write JS. In many occasions we just need to write code differently because of types, this is one of examples. To make the narrowing the discriminant needs to be explicitly checked.

Comment: I'm aware there's other ways of narrowing down the type like `in` or checking the discriminant, the reason I'm asking is because I want to avoid the if-block.

Comment: @VLAZ the reason I've used `as` is because if I do `const foobarEvent: FoobarEvent = { ... }`, then TS automatically narrows down the union type already so `foobarEvent` will be treated as `FooEvent` down the line. The event data is something that would come as an input. Would probably have been better to write a function to showcase this, but it's not really the point of the question.

Comment: @SimonHänisch that's because you have a `const`, so it's never reassigned. TS realises it cannot change types. You can [just use `declare`](https://tsplay.dev/mq8rZN) to abstract away the instantiation. Allows you to use the type intellisense and similar but the code doesn't work if ran. `declare` just tells the compiler "assume this thing exists".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If TypeScript would allow you to attach `.foo?.name` on any type, it would defeat type checking whenever we use `?.` operator.

For example, is my `foobarEvent` of a type, where `foo` is optional property:

```
type FoobarEvent = {
    id: number;
    bar: string;
    foo?: {
        name: string;
    }
}
```

in which case my intention is correct:

```
const name = foobarEvent.foo?.name;
```

or - did I create a typo by adding `.foo?.name` to a wrong type?

```
const name = localStorage.foo?.name;
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, but couldn't it detect that there's no `foo` in `typeof localStorage` at all?

Comment: That's what it does on your `BarEvent` type. I think it would become more confusing than helpful if TypeScript would default to what you propose. It's a good question though - where would be the right balance for this feature?

Comment: What I meant was that it could detect whether one of the types that make up `localStorage` contains `foo`, and if so, narrow it down to that type. But then I guess that feature would have to be limited to union types, so yeah maybe it's a rather confusing idea.

Comment: Problem is, that what you want to achieve is not narrowing. You just want to escape type-checking for certain case. If your `FooEvent | BarEvent` is only `BarEvent` during runtime, narrowing to `FooEvent` type is wrong. Also, what happens when union type contains more than 2 constituents?

Comment: Ok yeah I see one of the problems now. But I'm not sure why you mean that I want to escape type checking instead of narrowing? I want to extract `foo.name` from the event data only if the event is of type `FooEvent`, i. e. if `foo` exists in the event. Maybe the real (underlying) question is why in TypeScript the type can be narrowed with `if ('foo' in eventData)` but not with `if (eventData.foo)`?

Comment: You need to considered how many side effects you would produce with this. For example `if (eventData.foo)` is valid JavaScript construct that returns `false` for `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `0`, `false` etc...  it does not guaranty `FooEvent` type to be inside of the `if` branch when it's `true`.

Comment: The same is true for `if ('foo' in eventData)` though, `foo` could be anything at runtime. The only difference is that TypeScript can use this expression a lot more easily to narrow the type, because we're not trying to access the property already. `eventData.foo` can exist in a lot of different expressions (like an assignment) so it would need to consider the context to even figure out whether type narrowing would be possible, whereas `'foo' in eventData` is always a boolean expression.

Comment: That is not correct. If you have `eventData.foo = 0`, `if (eventData.foo) {` will resolve to `false`, while `if ("foo" in eventData) {` will resolve to `true`. One of the main reasons why TypeScript was introduced in the first place, was to help developer avoid this kind of errors due to ambiguity in JavaScript behavior.